# Trying to design a Gui based Boolean logic to Boolean Equation program

Tags: user-interface, boolean

my job is in automation and I deal a lot with Boolean logic for when a piece of equipment has permission to do something or not do something. this requires that I design expressions in simple one line equations. I'm trying to figure out how I can design a little helper app to make it easier to code.

For example, let's say I'm trying to design a permissive to allow a vehicle to start moving, just jumping into a car won't make it start going, there steps that need to happen before the car will go any where. such as turning on the motor. i'f you look at the image below you can kind of get an idea of a simpler equation.

https://i.ibb.co/fnQ3x9x/IMG-2389.jpg

The eq for the picture is:
Start Permission = MotorTurnedOn AND ((AutoMode OR (ManualMode AND (OilTempNorm OR OilCoolingActive))) OR EmerOvr)

A lot of time I'm editing code that someone wrote a long time ago so it's not always easy to understand and some are very long as seen in the picture below

https://i.ibb.co/tXtrKwk/IMG-2388.jpg

the picture are generated by a third party software that is used to create the GUI's for the equipment.

I'm trying to figure how how could I design something where I could take block and drop them into something resembling the picture and it could export an equation for the equivalent boolean expression.

I'm only familiar with Python, Matlab, C++ and a little bit of java, if there's some template out there that could help me get started I'd be willing to learn a new language otherwise, i'd wanna stick closer to what I know.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.